# initialisation of iterator with a reference

Tags: c++11, iterator

in C++11: I want to create an iterator from a reference. this is to make a loop starting from a given position rather than from begin().

I tried:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator ref2iter(T& x)
{
    return &x ;
} ;
```

but was answered:

```
conversion from ‘double*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >}’ requested
```

Comment: Although both `std::vector<T>::iterator` and `T*` can be dereferenced to T, they are different types... iterator is an object which implements specific ++, -- and other operators, while `T*` is just a built-in pointer type.

Comment: Also if you just want to get an iterator from a certain position, you can just use `it = vector.begin() + n`

Comment: actually, I need to do the reverse operation: pointer artithmetics to know the distance from the begining to T

Comment: iterator implements - operator already.